# Unable to activate VS Code Command Line Tool

Tags: visual-studio-code, command, command-line-interface

I am running the most recent versions of iTerm2 and Visual Studio Code.

Currently, running a terminal command like `code .` gives me an error message: `-bash: code: command not found`.

The [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac) recommends activating the command line tool via the Command Pallette inside VSCode, like so:

[the official documentation's screenshot for the command pallette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Leepn.png)

But when I run that command in the Command Pallette, I get an endless `searching...` prompt regardless of what permutation of the command I try to run:

[my command pallette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFsLQ.png)

I also tried running the following command from the documentation in my terminal:

```
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

As well as editing my .bash_profile directly and restarting my terminal. However, I still get `-bash: code: command not found`.

This is such a simple thing that I feel like I must be doing something obvious wrong, but I haven no idea what it is. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

When following [official guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac), it will create a soft link for `code` at `/usr/local/bin`

So you can do that action manually if the pallets is not working for you.
Run `echo $PATH` first to check if `/usr/local/bin` in `PATH` variable. If not, you can run `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"` to add the directory to `PATH` (this will effect current session only. Read on for permanent solution)

```sh
ln -s "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" /usr/local/bin/code
```

For this command, you should remove `\` after the first `"` since it will escape the `$`.

```sh
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
```

Also, the `.bash_profile` might not work if you moved to `zsh` instead of using `bash`. For `zsh`, you can add `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"` to the last line of `.zshrc`, create it if it's missing. Run `echo $SHELL` to check what terminal you are using